# How do I know the network activity proceeds？

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

The network activity indicator spins in the status bar while network activity proceeds. It disappears when network activity stops.

But there's nothing except `networkActivityIndicatorVisible` in `UIApplication` Class.

How can I get the "Network Activity Indicator" object on the status bar?
Or if there is a Notification when activity proceeds?

I need to monitor network activity.

Comment: How are you making your network requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the information provided in `UIApplication` class reference::

**networkActivityIndicatorVisible**

A Boolean value that turns an indicator of network activity on or off.

```
@property(nonatomic, getter=isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible) BOOL networkActivityIndicatorVisible
```

Discussion

Specify YES if the application should show network activity and NO if it should not. The default value is NO. A spinning indicator in the status bar shows network activity. The application may explicitly hide or show this indicator.
Availability

---

So check with **isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible**. I guess this what you want.

Comment: Checking with isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible works. It seems there is no notification can do this. Thanks

Comment: You can run a thread which timely checks for this visibility. When it changes you can raise a notification on that moment.